# Question about applicative and nested Maybe

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, option-type

I wrote this function:

```
appFunc :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool -> Maybe (Integer,Integer)
appFunc i1 i2 b = if b then Just (i1,i2) else Nothing
```

And then I use it as such in GHCi:

```
> appFunc <$> Just 3 <*> Nothing <*> Just True
Nothing
```

Which is great because if at least one of the parameters is `Nothing` then the whole expression evaluates to `Nothing`. However, when all parameters are `Just` then I get a nested `Maybe`:

```
> appFunc <$> Just 3 <*> Just 1 <*> Just False
Just Nothing
```

Ideally, I would like it to evaluate to plain old `Nothing`. So my solution was to use `join`:

```
> join $ appFunc <$> Just 3 <*> Just 1 <*> Just True
Just (3,1)
```

Is there a better solution or cleaner style? I was experimenting with the monad `>>=` function but with no success. For example I tried writing:

```
> Just True >>= appFunc <$> Just 3 <*> Just 1
* Couldn't match expected type `Bool -> Maybe b'
              with actual type `Maybe (Bool -> Maybe (Integer, Integer))'
* Possible cause: `(<*>)' is applied to too many arguments
  In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely
    `appFunc <$> Just 5 <*> Just 4'
  In the expression: Just True >>= appFunc <$> Just 5 <*> Just 4
  In an equation for `it':
      it = Just True >>= appFunc <$> Just 5 <*> Just 4
* Relevant bindings include
    it :: Maybe b (bound at <interactive>:51:1)
```

This error makes sense to me because:

```
 appFunc <$> Just 3 <*> Just 1 :: m (a -> m b)
```

whereas `>>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

Is there a monad solution or should I just stick to the applicative style with `join`?

Comment: I can't think of anything simpler. I thought about defining a custom `<$>`-like combinator, but it seems unfeasible because the original expression is parsed as `(((appFunc <$> Just 3) <*> Just 1) <*> Just True)` so even redefining `<$>` does not help (unless we want something which only works with arity 3).

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that `join` *is* a monad solution: `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`, `join mm = mm >>= id` and `m >>= f = join (f <$> m)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
module Main where

import Data.Bool

appFunc :: Integer -> Integer -> Bool -> Maybe (Integer, Integer)
appFunc i1 i2 what = bool Nothing (Just (i1,i2)) what

result = do
  i1 <- Just 1
  i2 <- Just 2
  test <- Just True
  appFunc i1 i2 test

result2 = Just 1 >>= \i1 -> Just 2 >>= \i2 -> Just True >>= appFunc i1 i2 

main = do
  print result
  print result2
```

Your `appFunc` is more like a typical `monadFunc`. As duplode already mentioned, using `join` is just a monad solution, I just rephrased that into the more idiomatic style.

To get a better intuition of those things, let's look at the signature of the central applicative operation

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

All three parameters to `(<*>)` are applicatively wrapped values and `(<*>)` knows the "wrapping" before it needs to peak into it, to do something with them. For example

```
Just (+1) <*> Just 5
```

here, the calculation involving the "wrapped" function `(+1)` and the "wrapped" value `5` can't alter the "wrapping" `Just` in this case.

Your `appFunc` on the other hand, needs pure values to produce something in a "wrapping". That's not applicative. Here we need to do some calculations with the values, to know, what a constituent part of the "wrapping" will be.

Let's look at the central monadic operation:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Here the second parameter does exactly that. It is a function taking a pure value and returning something in a wrapping. Just like `appFunc i1 i2`.

Comment: Thanks, the usage of `do` was a big idiomatic AHA moment!