# Monads = Functors + Idempotency (of type)?

Tags: haskell, monads

In Haskell, Monads are defined by kleisli triple.

In Category theory in general, is it fine to say:

Monads = Functors + [Idempotency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) of the monadic type (not the value)?

Comment: Hi, you should visit [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) or [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour) for questions not specific to any source code. Also please take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973336/monads-not-with-flatmap-but-flatunit ?

Comment: @jberryman Presumably it is a follow-up to that one (cf. the comments to the answer there). Note that the rollback war on that question appears to have caused a 24-hour suspension of the OP.

Answer (score 7):

No, a monad is emphatically not idempotent: although there is a requirement that there be a natural transformation

```
mu_x : T(T(x)) -> T(x)
```

it is in general *not* the case that the two objects selected in this way are equal, that is,

```
T(T(x)) = T(x)
```

does not generally hold, even up to isomorphism.

Even in the restricted land of Haskell `Monad` it is easy to see this in action: `Maybe (Maybe ())` and `Maybe ()` are clearly inequal types with different numbers of semantic objects; ignoring bottoms:

```
Nothing, Just () -- Maybe ()
Nothing, Just Nothing, Just (Just ()) -- Maybe (Maybe ())
```

or with bottoms:

```
_|_, Nothing, Just _|_, Just () -- Maybe ()
_|_, Nothing, Just _|_, Just Nothing, Just (Just _|_), Just (Just ()) -- Maybe (Maybe ())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question. about "T(T(x)) = T(x)
does not generally hold, even up to isomorphism.". I thought that if it's an Identity monad that is isomorohism, `T(T(x)) = T(x)` holds. Am I wrong?

Comment: @bayesian-study You are not wrong. But most monads are not the Identity monad.

Comment: "does not generally hold, even up to isomorphism" seems to mean as if `T(T(x)) = T(x)` does Not hold on isomophism identiy monad.

Comment: @bayesian-study It means that it does not hold *in general* -- that is, across all monads.